# What is the register_globals warning message that is appearing?

Tags: php, warnings, register-globals

I have one of my pages redirect to a page called customproofs.php.

When it redirects to that page, the following Warning message appears:

> **Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly
>   relies on a session side-effect which
>   existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be
>   advised that the session extension
>   does not consider global variables as
>   a source of data, unless
>   register_globals is enabled. You can
>   disable this functionality and this
>   warning by setting
>   session.bug_compat_42 or
>   session.bug_compat_warn to off,
>   respectively in Unknown on line 0**

Does this mean I need to change something in the php.ini file? How would I change the php.ini file for a specific folder on a web server?

Is changing the setting just so the message goes away? Why am I receiving this message?

The code works fine as it is now. Could I just tell the warning not to appear?

Comment: you shouldn't change the php.ini, because it's a security feature.
pleas post the code that is responsible for this warning

Comment: which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: @Jens - I have no idea what part of the code is responsible because the error message says to look on line 0 and I have no idea what the error is referring to.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid this by not using the same names for session variables and regular variables.

e.g. if you had

```
$foo = 'Hello';
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Bar';
```

try changing this to:

```
$foo = 'Hello';
$_SESSION['session_foo'] = 'Bar';
```

Comment: What is wrong with using a variable named $address and another variable named $_SESSION['address']?

Comment: @zeckdude that's a long story. you'd better do that. Or at least initialize your $_SESSION['address'] with non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty odd error message.
To avoid this one and many other pitfalls, just never the same names to the session variable and a global variable. I.e. Having in the same script variables `$_SESSION['cart']` and  `$cart` is wrong, while `$_SESSION['sess_cart']` and  `$cart` is all right.
Also, I hope you don't use ancient session syntax, `session_register()` one